# Как сделать выезжающий sidebar в мобильной версии сайта при верстке с использованием Bootstrap?

Tags: html, jquery, css, вёрстка, bootstrap

Верстаю макет с использованием Bootstrap. Появилась необходимость сделать так чтобы sideebar слева (скриншот приложил) в мобильной версии скрывался и его можно было сделать выезжающим при нажатии на кнопку или ваще свайпом от края экран. Подскажите пожалуйста как это реализовать?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не бутстрап, но думаю не составит особого труда под него это сделать:

```js
$('.menu_icon, .close').on('click', function(){
 $('.menu-mobile--itself').toggleClass('show')
})
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
}

.wrapper {
  border: 1px solid #333;
  margin: 30px auto;
  max-width: 768px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 768px;
  padding: 10px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.menu-mobile--itself {
  position: absolute;
  padding: 30px;
  background-color: #333;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(100%);
          transform: translateX(100%);
  -webkit-transition: cubic-bezier(0.52, 0.26, 0, 0.92) 0.5s;
  transition: cubic-bezier(0.52, 0.26, 0, 0.92) 0.5s;
  color: #fff;
}
.menu-mobile--itself.show {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
          transform: translateX(0);
}
.menu-mobile--itself .close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  right: 15px;
  font-size: 22px;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.menu_block {
  border: 1px solid #f2f2f2;
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}
.menu_block .logo, .menu_block .menu_icon {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 50%;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.menu_block .logo {
  padding: 10px;
}
.menu_block .logo img {
  max-width: 200px;
  width: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.menu_block .menu_icon {
  font-size: 32px;
  text-align: right;
  padding: 0 30px;
  -webkit-transition: 500ms;
  transition: 500ms;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.menu_block .menu_icon:hover {
  color: #727272;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="wrapper">
 <div class="menu-mobile--itself">
  <div class="close">
   <i class="fa fa-times-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  </div>
  <ul>
   <li>Option #1</li>
   <li>Option #2</li>
   <li>Option #3</li>
   <li>Option #4</li>
   <li>Option #5</li>
  </ul>  
 </div>
 <div class="menu_block">
  <div class="image-block logo">
   <img src="http://www.juggcash.com/images/hd_tools/default_logo.png" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div class="menu_icon">
   <i class="fa fa-bars" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```